Django views.py to create a database
Instead of using the native models.py to create a db instead I either use mySQL to create or use: `def query_and_update_db(self, table_name, data):
    try:
        # Create table SQL
        create_table_sql = f"""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
            open FLOAT NOT NULL,
            high FLOAT NOT NULL,
            low FLOAT NOT NULL,
            close FLOAT NOT NULL,
            volume FLOAT NOT NULL,
            UNIQUE (timestamp)
        );
        """
        logger.debug(f"Executing SQL: {create_table_sql}")

        # Insert data SQL
        insert_query = f"""
        INSERT INTO {table_name} (timestamp, open, high, low, close, volume)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        ON CONFLICT (timestamp) DO UPDATE
        SET open = EXCLUDED.open,
            high = EXCLUDED.high,
            low = EXCLUDED.low,
            close = EXCLUDED.close,
            volume = EXCLUDED.volume;
        """

        # Database interaction with explicit transaction handling
        with connections['fourth_db'].cursor() as cursor:
            try:
                # Start a transaction explicitly
                cursor.execute("BEGIN")
                logger.debug("Transaction started.")

                # Execute table creation
                cursor.execute(create_table_sql)
                logger.debug("Table creation SQL executed.")

                # Verify the unique constraint for timestamp
                cursor.execute(f"""
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM information_schema.table_constraints
                WHERE table_name = '{table_name}' AND constraint_type = 'UNIQUE' AND constraint_name = 'unique_timestamp';
                """)
                if cursor.fetchone()[0] == 0:
                    logger.debug("Unique constraint does not exist, adding it.")
                    cursor.execute(f"""
                    ALTER TABLE {table_name}
                    ADD CONSTRAINT unique_timestamp UNIQUE (timestamp);
                    """)

                # Log the data being inserted
                logger.debug(f"Data to be inserted: {data.head()}")

                # Insert data
                for index, row in data.iterrows():
                    try:
                        cursor.execute(insert_query, tuple(row))
                        logger.debug(f"Inserted row {index} into table {table_name}.")
                    except Exception as e:
                        logger.error(f"Error inserting row {index}: {e}")

                # Commit the transaction manually
                logger.debug("About to commit transaction.")
                connections['fourth_db'].commit()
                logger.debug("Transaction committed successfully.")

                return {"status": "success", "message": "Data successfully uploaded"}

            except Exception as e:
                connections['fourth_db'].rollback()
                logger.error(f"Transaction rolled back due to error: {e}")
                return {"status": "error", "message": str(e)}

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Database operation error: {e}")
        return {"status": "error", "message": str(e)}`

To create and als query the db, After succesfully creating the table can't find it in the db why?
Tried logging and so many error handiling pattern.

Please can you exlplain what you did,
I sincerely didn't get the change you made.
Thanks.
